# Does Magic Find buffs also applies to loot bags I open

Tags: guild-wars-2

There are several ways to buff your magic find in Guild Wars 2 (Banners, Food, Black Lion Boosters, etc). Does any of those help get better loot when I open loot bags (e.g. [Champion loot bag](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Champion_loot_bag)) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless the loot bag explicitly states in the tooltip that it *is* affected by Magic Find (as some do), you should assume that Magic Find will not affect any loot bags or other containers that you open.

As stated in the [Magic Find](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Magic_Find) wiki article, Magic Find generally only affects the loot received directly when you slay a creature. It does not affect chests, the Mystic Forge, or any other sources of loot. It essentially increases the chances that you'll roll a higher "rarity category" in a slain creature's loot table.

It's unclear to me whether the boss chests received after killing a world boss count as a "creature kill" or a "chest" for the purposes of Magic Find. There seems to be an unofficial consensus that the contents of boss chests count as a "creature kill" and are therefore affected; with the loot being generated when the boss dies and then just held in the chest, the same way that creature loot is held on its body (or in a Wooden Chest/Steel Chest, if a rare/exotic was dropped) until you collect it.

Answer (score 1):

The only bags in the game that are affected by your Magic Find are bags obtained through sPvP (so that Magic Find is not entirely useless to PvP players). All other bags are not affected by Magic Find.

Magic Find affects the items that enemies drop. This means that higher Magic Find will increase your chances of finding bags, but it will not affect the loot you get from the bags.

Comment: Not quite true: Divine Lucky Envelopes, and HoT meta event rewards are also affected by MF - read the first part of [Magic Find](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Magic_Find) on the wiki.

Comment: Oh, right. I knew about the envelopes but I didn't know about the meta rewards. That's awesome!

Comment: This is false at this point. A lot of lootbags (specifically variations of champion loot bags) are affected by magic find and it is stated in the game.

Comment: @Zero Feel free to make an updated answer and hopefully the Asker will change the accepted answer.